# Docked multiline textbox is covered by StatusStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, statusstrip

I am having a form in which I have multiple line textbox and status strip both docked to the bottom of the form.

Textbox must be docked so it can be resizable while the whole form is resizable.

The problem is that the status strip is covering the textbox on the bottom of the from covering scroll bars down arrow.

Is there any way to make textbox docked to the bottom while still displaying above the status strip?

Regards.

Comment: I have solved the problem. The Panel woulds do the job perfectly. It can be docked to fill the page and it does not cover/go under the status bar, then I can easily dock my textbox inside of it. This works perfectly, and everything is resizable when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can use Anchor property to resize control when parent resize.  By default it set to top  left corner.  If you enable the bottom than textbox will be shrink or expand as form change size.

Comment: Anchoring is the best option when space is to be left. In this situation, docking is the best option with the ZOrder set correctly.

Answer (score 36):

Right click the text box and click `Bring to front` (Or the Statusbar and `Send to back` if there are other controls). The docking is based on the ZOrder of the controls on the form with the front most being the inner most.

Comment: This is what helped in my case, thanks - I knew about docking order, but didn't realize you could do that with these options instead of recreating things in different order or messing in designer code.

Answer (score 8):

You could also use a [ToolStripContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontainer.aspx), which will take care of what you are trying to do and is generally an efficient way of placing toolstrips such as the statusstrip.